# Connotation meant by "B of A" and "A's B". What would be the differences?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, possessives, connotations

Do you agree with the interpretation of the following three example sentences?

> 1. I don't want to be involved in ***the problems of my boss***.
>    The boss probably deals with some problems. e.g. slow
>    sales, product quality issue, customer complaint

> 2. I don't want to be involved in ***my boss's problem***.
>    This implies a similar case as above one, but with only one problem.

> 3. I don't want to be involved in ***the problem of my boss***.
>    Probably the boss himself has caused trouble. e.g. a misconduct

If you agree, then

Q1) Why is "***my boss's problem***" likely to mean that my boss has ONLY ONE problem?

Q2) why is "***the problem of my boss***" LESS LIKELY to mean that my boss has only one problem, but MORE LIKELY to mean that the boss himself probably has caused trouble?

Comment: [how come x? Very informal. Better: Why does x mean or Why is x likely to mean etc.]

Answer (score 1):

Sounding like a native English speaker (any standard variety of English)

I disagree with the interpretation provided for this simple reason:

**My boss's problem** [singular] and **My boss's problems** [plural] are the simplest and most idiomatic way of expressing what ails the boss: one problem or more problems than one.

The "of the" point is just awkward. In actual speech, using the "of the" option **here** sounds non-native or non-idiomatic.

- I don't want to be involved with **my boss's **problem**** OR **boss's problems**.

Comment: _The problem of X_ implies a problem caused by, or concerning X e.g. _the problem of evil_, whereas _X's problem_ means a problem experienced by X.

Comment: my boss's problem, my boss's problems, the problem or problems of my boss = all the same semantically except for one is singular and one is plural. . I don't think  you can teach me anything here. Sorry. Your examples are not **relevant** here.

Comment: Well, that is how _I_ understand _the problem of X_.

Comment: And you no. 3. is most naturally expressed by _the problem(s) **with** my boss_.

Comment: @ColinFine My number 3?? 1 and 3 are the same except for plural and singular. And "I don't want to be involved in the problem(s) with my boss." **means something else**.